# IIS 8.5 How to redirect http://www. to https://www. with status code 301?

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

How to redirect http://www. to https://www. with status code 301 without code 302 ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the URL redirect code in web.config with redirect type as permanent (301)

```
<system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

add this under configuration tag in web.config

Comment: Thanks, but I have another problem. Why if i trying enter http://www.example.com i get status code 302 and i am get https://example.com, then me redirect on https://www.examplecom. with code 301 ?

Comment: are you trying to say that `redirectType="Permanent"` gives you 302 instead of 301?

Comment: Ok, but if i enter with http www i get status 302 and then redirect 301.But i need only status 301 without 302